# Stop on last element iterators C++

Tags: c++, iterator, c++11

What is the most elegant way to perform a loop and stop after the second to last element (in C++11)?

Note: I mean for bidirectional iterators; random access iterators are a trivial special case, of course, because they have `+` and `-` operators.

```
std::list<double> x{1,2,3,4,5,6};

for (auto iter = x.begin(); iter != x.end(); ++iter) {
  auto iter2 = iter;
  ++iter2;
  if (iter2 == x.end()) break;
  std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you did not mean "forward iterators" instead of "bidirectional iterators"? The bidirectional case seems pretty trivial as well.

Comment: @LucTouraille `std::list` gives bidirectional iterators, so that is fine with me-- can you show the trivial solution you're thinking of?

Comment: If `while (iter != x.end() - 1)` is trivial to you, then `while (iter != --x.end())` should be pretty straightforward too, no?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `std::prev` function:

```
std::list<double> x{1,2,3,4,5,6};

for (auto iter = x.begin(); iter != std::prev(x.end()); ++iter) {
  std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I can't say I see anything particularly compelling about `std::prev` here. More typing is better? ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn Well, I got a bit confused by "second to last element" and thought it would be `std::prev(x.end(), 2)` :S

Comment: @MarkRansom Really my goal is to iterate through adjacent items in pairs (e.g. performing finite differencing on a list of items: fd[i] = a[i+1] - a[i]), so I think the best solution is to start at `iter = std::next(x.begin())` and stop at `x.end()`. Then, inside the loop, I'll look at `*iter - *std::prev(iter)`. That should be safe for lists containing 0 or 1 elements.

Answer (score 5):

In C++03 it would have been:

```
for (std::list<double>::iterator it = x.begin(), it_last = --x.end();
     it != it_last; ++it)
{
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
}
```

In C++11, there's nothing fundamentally different, it's just less verbose..:

```
for (auto it = begin(x), it_last = --end(x); it != it_last; ++it)
{
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `x.end()--` should be `--x.end()`.

Comment: @Luc : Yeah, I was thinking that `--end(x)` wouldn't work for iterators in general (i.e. if the iterator were in fact just a pointer), but then I realized that `end(x)--` wouldn't either. :-P

Comment: In practice this may be more typing than R. Martinho's answer, because that works for any bidirectional iterator, whereas this doesn't. So if used in an algorithm that takes an iterator, this would need either specialization/overloading for pointers or tag dispatch for random access iterators in general. But if `std::list` is intended to be the whole question, rather than just an example, then this will do.

Comment: @Steve : Aside from pointers, this should work with any bidirectional iterator as well. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I don't think you're missing something, that's exactly what I said. The fact that it doesn't work for pointers, whereas `std::prev` does, means that in the situation where you want a solution that works for any bidirectional iterator, this requires more typing. I was briefly describing what that extra typing is, in case anyone ever tries to use this answer :-)

Comment: @Steve : Ah, understood; apparently I didn't read your comment thoroughly enough ('random access' caught my eye, 'pointers' didn't).

Comment: @ildjarn: I was probably a bit unclear -- treating all random-access iterators specially is sufficient but not necessary. I'm also slightly concerned about the possibility of a container for which `end` returns a const object. I suspect it's illegal, because I expect `container::end()` defines the return type as `container::iterator`, but I'm not going to check right now.

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement on R. Martinho Fernandes answer:

Use the `std::prev` function:

```
std::list<double> x{1,2,3,4,5,6};

for (auto iter = x.begin(), end=std::prev(x.end()); iter != end; ++iter) {
  std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
}
```

This only calculates: `std::prev(x.end())` once.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't even think of this improvement. If I were to improve that code, I'd go straight to `for(auto&& x : drop_last(x))`: same performance characteristics, no readability lost (on the contrary).

Comment: Does anyone know if there will be any performance gain with compiler optimization (i.e. `-O3` w/ gcc)?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes +1 for `drop_last`, even though my application is better with the `std::prev(...)` to the range-loop here (in each loop iteration I need to use `*iter` and (what I'm guessing is) `*std::next(iter)`).

Comment: No, the range-based loop has no iterators. `x` is a reference to the value.